# Packers that partially decrypts contents on-the-fly

Tags: pe, elf, packers, protection

I'm on the lookout for packers that I could use/read the source for, that don't decrypt the contents of the original binary in one go and jump to it. Do you know of any packer that decodes/decrypts a functions contents on the fly(when it is called) and jumps to it? Or of any packer/protector that does anything similar?

Comment: Armadillo (R.I.P.) did this, but it isn't open-source.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is 'virtualization'. it never even decrypts the code; it simply translates it to its own machine code and then interprets it.

Comment: @AcidShout Thanks-- but no, I'm actually looking for a packer that does on-the-fly decoding of some sort. More than anything, I'm curious to play with a sample that uses such a packer.

Comment: Shrinker might be easier in that respect - it installs an exception handler which intercepts the first access to individual pages, and they are decompressed only at that time.  Not open source, but a very easy read.